# IMPORTRANGE contains specific columns with multiple answers

Tags: google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange, regexextract

Example, one person can enter 5 events with several options for participating (both days or Sunday only or 1st go....)  how do I get master1 sheet to only show contestants on Saturday and master2 only Sunday?

"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YxcIHEHwdvTcjcoMv8YN0AGByxaI9u1WylTjk3f0ABs/edit#gid=705727401"

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please authorize access and modification to those who have the link

Comment: While links to external content might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. Considering this, please add all the relevant details directly into the question body (please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask])?

Comment: anyone?  I made the file shareable - my deadline is Monday June 27 noon.  Thank You